ArgumentCaptor works on String type but fail on Intent type
I have a function with two argument, one is android Intent, another one is String.
I use ArgumentCaptor to capture it but the Intent Object verify fail, the String one works fine.
Error:
Expected :hello_action
Actual   :null

Code:
PersonService .java
public class PersonService {

    public static void sendBroadcast(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("hello_action");
        intent.putExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED);
        PersonRepository.sendBroadcast(intent,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    }
}

PersonRepository .java
public class PersonRepository {
    public static String TAG = MainActivity.TAG;
    public static void sendBroadcast(Intent intent,String perms) {
        Log.i(TAG,"send intent");
    }
}

Test code:
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Context.class,
PersonService.class,PersonRepository.class})
public class PersonServiceTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockStatic(PersonRepository.class);
    }
    @After
    public void destory() {

    }
   
    @Test
    public void testSendBroadcast() throws Exception {
        Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Intent> captorIntent = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> captorString = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

        PersonService.sendBroadcast(mockContext);
        verifyStatic(PersonRepository.class,times(1));
        PersonRepository.sendBroadcast(captorIntent.capture(),captorString.capture());

        Intent intent = captorIntent.getValue();
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,-1);
        //Assert.assertEquals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED,state);
        Assert.assertEquals(ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,captorString.getValue());
        Assert.assertEquals("hello_action",captorIntent.getValue());

    }
}

